# Refactoring Complicated Nested Node.js Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, refactoring

I have the following snippet of code below. It currently works, but I'm hoping to optimize/refactor it a bit.

Basically, it fetches JSON data, extracts the urls for a number of PDFs from the response, and then downloads those PDFs into a folder.

*I'm hoping to refactor this code in order to process the PDFs once they are all downloaded. Currently, I'm not sure how to do that. There are a lot of nested asynchronous functions going on.*

How might I refactor this to allow me to tack on another `.then` call before my error handler, so that I can then process the PDFs that are downloaded?

```
const axios = require("axios");
const moment = require("moment");
const fs = require("fs");
const download = require("download");
const mkdirp = require("mkdirp"); //  Makes nested files...
const getDirName = require("path").dirname; // Current directory name...

const today = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");

function writeFile(path, contents, cb){
  mkdirp(getDirName(path), function(err){
    if (err) return cb(err)
      fs.writeFile(path, contents, cb)
  })
};

axios.get(`http://federalregister.gov/api/v1/public-inspection-documents.json?conditions%5Bavailable_on%5D=${today}`)
  .then((res) => {
    res.data.results.forEach((item) => {
      download(item.pdf_url).then((data) => {
        writeFile(`${__dirname}/${today}/${item.pdf_file_name}`, data, (err) => {
          if(err){
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            console.log("FILE WRITTEN: ", item.pdf_file_name);
          }
        })
      })
    })
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("COULD NOT DOWNLOAD FILES: \n", err);
  })
```

Thanks for any help you all can provide.

P.S. –– When I simply tack on the `.then` call right now, it fires immediately. This means that my forEach loop is non-blocking? I thought that forEach loops were blocking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current `forEach` will run *synchronously*, and will not wait for the asynchronous operations to complete. You should use `.map` instead of `forEach` so you can map each item to its `Promise` from `download`. Then, you can use `Promise.all` on the resulting array, which will resolve once all `download`s are complete:

```
axios.get(`http://federalregister.gov/api/v1/public-inspection-documents.json?conditions%5Bavailable_on%5D=${today}`)
  .then(processResults)
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("COULD NOT DOWNLOAD FILES: \n", err);
  });
function processResults(res) {
  const downloadPromises = res.data.results.map((item) => (
    download(item.pdf_url).then(data => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      writeFile(`${__dirname}/${today}/${item.pdf_file_name}`, data, (err) => {
        if(err) reject(err);
        else resolve(console.log("FILE WRITTEN: ", item.pdf_file_name));
      });
    }))
  ));
  return Promise.all(downloadPromises)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('all done');
    });
}
```

If you wanted to essentially block the function on each iteration, you would want to use an `async` function in combination with `await` instead.

Comment: Hmmm, I understand the idea, but when I use your code the "all done" block is not firing for me. Files are downloading though. Am I missing something?

Comment: It *should* work, note that the Promise chain spawned by `download` is being implicitly returned in the `.map` - you copied that, right? (parentheses, not curly bracket)

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a problem with your solution, but for some reason the script is consistently failing to download all of the resources... There are 126 pdf links, which are consistently identified by the request to the first link. But the downloader function is failing to download all of them. Here's my git: https://github.com/KingOfCramers/federal-register-searcher

Comment: If the `download` function is normal, it should throw an error if there's a problem, which means the error will be visible in the upper `catch`, right?

Comment: Perhaps it's a problem with the connection? It's only downloading 84 of the 126 files.... Are you getting the same problem, if you download the git? Please let me know if you're able to help out, thx

Comment: It was a limiting issue. Thanks!